# Upload Image Web Api

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-web-api, syncfusion

I'm trying to add the upload box from SyncFusion to my Web App. I added the Upload Box:

```
<div id="targetElement">
                <div id="UploadDefault"></div>
            </div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        //Declaration
        $("#UploadDefault").ejUploadbox({
            saveUrl: "/api/project/uploadimage"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I want to add using an WebApi Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("project/uploadimage")]
        public async Task UploadFile(string fileName, string description)
        {
}
```

But I always get the http response:

The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `"/api/project/uploadimage"` in your JS code whereas your attribute routing is `project/uploadimage`. You're also using parameters in your method, so if you want them to be passed through the url you need to add them in the `Route` attribute (`[Route("api/project/uploadimage/{fileName}/{description}")]`), otherwise you need to get them from the body, so you need to use [FromBody] attribute on your method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/project/uploadimage")]
    public async Task UploadFile([FromBody] string fileName,[FromBody] string description)
    {
    }
```

Comment: The "/api" part is from the route prefix, of that controler, I forgot to mention that. The part of "[FromBody]" I'll try it. Thanks!